# Ограничить JOIN одной строкой

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица MySQL с заказами и timestamp и id этих заказов, а есть таблица с обработкой заказов, но обработок может быть несколько. связка по id заказа.
Хочется сделать выборку заказов за некий интервал дат (BETWEEN) и присоеденить к ней по одной обработке этого заказа самой "первой" из всех по этому заказу, ну по сути ближайшую по дате.
Возможно ли это сделать одним запросом? По сути нужно ограничить LEFT JOIN одной строкой, на эту тему много всего, но у меня чего-то не получается.
Смысл в SQL:

```
SELECT o.id,o.date,p.date.p.state,p.some_column   
FROM orders o  
LEFT JOIN process p ON p.order=o.id AND p.date>=o.date ORDER BY p.date LIMIT 1  
WHERE o.date BETWEEN '2018-01-21 08:00' AND '2018-01-21 21:00'   
ORDER BY o.date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.id, o.date, p.date, p.state, p.some_column   
FROM orders o left join
(select p.* from process p join 
(select p.order, min(p.date) as date from process p 
where p.date >= '2018-01-21 08:00' group by p.order) x 
on p.order = x.order and p.date = x.date) p 
on o.id = p.order 
WHERE o.date BETWEEN '2018-01-21 08:00' AND '2018-01-21 21:00'   
ORDER BY o.date
```

Comment: `from p.order` так и должно быть?

Comment: Нет, опечатался, вместо from p.order должно быть from process p.

Comment: Ну я так и подумал. Спасибо. Пробую.